# Making website scalable on mobile with viewport meta tag

Tags: android, html, iphone, viewport, meta

Morning all,

Im trying to get my site so people can pinch to zoom on mobiles and so that it loads at the right size.

Currently on an iPhone the site loads zoomed in (everything looks big) but you can pinch zoom it out so it fits the width of the phone.

On Chrome for android however pinch to zoom does not work at all and the website it quite zoomed in (does not fit to device width).

I'm currently using the Meta:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

in my head tag, and have tried a few variants of this that I've found across the web while researching. this seems to have no effect.

Another thing to not is that all pages on the iPhone pinch to zoom works however this code is only on the home page currently.... which makes me think that the browser is enabling pinch to zoom on iPhones. Not this Code....

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The code that you mentioned gives the limitation to the amount of zoom that you can do.
In your case, for example, max zoom can be upto 12 times the initial size and zoom out can be done only upto 1/4th of the initial size which you have mentioned, i.e 1.0

To check, make `user-scalable=no` and `maximum-scale=1.0`
So, yeah, the browser handles the zoom, you can simply restrict it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help so far, I have changed the code to what you said however unfortunately it has made no difference. i will post my head code in a few comments below:

Comment: here is my head code in an open google doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/14U9Tjsn-nn1-zRNwcTWfV1omRJJWenYGgtNu0NVkDGU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: [here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) a small description of how things work.